# Move large column into another table

Tags: sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I want to move a column in my SQLite3 database that has a lot of data in it (>98% of the entire row's data is in this one column). I am thinking of moving this column out of the current table and into its own table to give performance benefits if I am searching down other (indexed) columns (due to paging/caching being significantly improved). How would I accomplish this in the "nicest" way? Just use a JOIN every time I query the database? Surely there has to be a nicer way.

Comment: Join is how you do it.  Its a 1 to 1 relationship, so there is probably not a heavy join.  But there are probably no real advantages to separate it in the first place.

Comment: If most of your queries don't use the large column, there might be an improvement. You can move the join into a view.